# Loop controls inside function in c

Tags: c, function, loops

I'm currently trying to use binary search I don't want it to return -1 if it doesn't find anything I just want it to return the next best possible solution to my target. Now for some strange reason, my if statements aren't being catch and I don't know why really. The only thing I'm thinking of is maybe the scope? But I'm not entirely sure if its just the way function work in c and I'm forgetting a small detail.

```
int binary_search(int list[][4], int bottom, int top,  int hit)
{

  printf("bottom: %d top %d \n", bottom,top);

  if (bottom > top)
    {
      if (list[top][0]<= hit && list[top][1] >= hit)
        return top;
      else if (list[bottom][0] <= hit && list[bottom][1] >= hit)
        return bottom;
    }
  int middle = (top+bottom)/2;

  if (hit < list[middle][0])
    return binary_search(list, bottom, middle-1, hit);

  else if (hit > list[middle][0])
    return binary_search(list, middle+1, top, hit);

  else if (hit == list[middle][0])
    return middle;


}
```

Comment: ``return = top`` ? This won't even compile, and by "loop" do you mean "recursion"? That's the only repetitive behavior I see here...

Comment: What do you mean by the next best possible solution? Surely the function name is saying that it is searching

Comment: I made a mistake on the return part but when I took out the equal it  still giving me trouble, and sorry about the miss type.

Comment: @Ed what I was searching for was a range of dates at first I was searching if my array had a beginning date that matches but if it doesn't I just return either one of them that falls the target I'm For example Looking for day 8:
[  1] begin 1 end 2 
[  2] begin 10 end 12

Comment: Write your function to return -1 if it can't find an element. Once you have that working correctly, then consider how to modify the "not found" base case that returns -1 so that it returns the nearest answer instead.

Comment: @ThaoNguyen - You need to get the search to find the first date by looking for the date that is greater than or equal to the search date. If equal ok - otherwise you need to step back one. This will be the start of the date range and because you array is sorted you can start scanning from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case when `hit > list[middle][0]` but `hit <= list[middle][1]`  In my opinion, in that case you should be returning `middle`, but you actually recurse into `binary_search` again having excluded the range in list[middle].

Comment: yea after I look back I just rewrote it and pick up on some logical errors I had rolling